# MySQL optimize sentence

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, select

I have a simple table where I have to extract some records. The problem is that the evaluation function is a very time-consuming stored procedure so I shouldn't to call it twice like in this sentence:

```
SELECT *, slow_sp(row) FROM table WHERE slow_sp(row)>0 ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 10
```

First I thought in optimize like this:

```
SELECT *, slow_sp(row) AS value FROM table WHERE value>0 ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it doesn't works due "value" is not processed when the WHERE clause is evaluated.

Any idea to optimize this sentence? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does slow_sp do? To begin optimizing the query you should add an index on `dist`.

To make your second query work, use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: slow_sp returns a value between 0 and 100 acording to the "importance" of a word in a text corpus. Basically access to an array of precalculated values to determine an int value.

I'll try the HAVING value. Thanks.

Comment: It's a MySQL function, right? Basicly add indexes on every column you are including in where statements. I can't help more without seeing the query in the function in question.

Comment: It's ok raveren. I forgoten HAVING clause can help. Now it's working. Thanks!